# Calling a helper from a class and instance method in a Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to call a helper method within a model, from both a class and an instance method, e.g. `Model.method(data)` and `model_instance.method`.  However, the class method always returns "NoMethodError: undefined method '**helper_method**' for #<Class ...>"

**model.rb:**

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ModelHelper

  def method
    helper_method(self.data)
  end

  def self.method(data)
    self.helper_method(data)
  end
end
```

**model_helper.rb:**

```
module ModelHelper
  def helper_method(data)
    # logic here
  end
end
```

I even tried adding `def self.helper_method(data)` in the helper to no avail.

After quite a bit of seraching, I wasn't able to find anything on how to achieve this, or at least anything that worked.

Comment: Is there more logic in `method` than just calling `helper_method`?

Comment: @jvillian: There doesn't have to be.  For purposes of this example, all that's required is the `helper_method` call.  Also: the answer is below 

Comment: No, of course there doesn't *have* to be. The reason I asked is because if, in your case, there isn't more logic, then you've made this rather more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 2):

The answer turned out to be pretty simple, and doesn't require any Rails magic: you just re-include the helper and define the class method within a class block:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ModelHelper

  def method
    helper_method(self.data)
  end

  # Expose Model.method()
  class << self
    include ModelHelper

    def method(data)
      helper_method(data)
    end
  end
end
```

No changes to the helper needed at all.

Now you can call `method` on both the class and an instance!

Answer (score 2):

If there's no additional logic in `method`, then you can simply do:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ModelHelper
  extend  ModelHelper
end
```

And get both the instance (`@model.helper_method`) and the class (`Model.helper_method`) methods.

If, for legacy (or other) reasons, you *still* want to use `method` as an instance *and* class method, but `method` doesn't do anything different than `helper_method`, then you could do:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ModelHelper
  extend  ModelHelper

  alias method helper_method
  singleton_class.send(:alias_method, :method, :helper_method)
end
```

And now you can do `@model.method` and `Model.method`.

BTW, using modules to include methods in classes is seductive, but can get away from you quickly if you're not careful, leaving you doing a lot of `@model.method(:foo).source_location`, trying to figure out where something came from. Ask me how I know...

Answer (score 0):

you need to define model_helper.rb as:

```
module ModelHelper
  def self.helper_method(data)
    # logic here
  end
end
```

and call this method in model.rb as:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ModelHelper

  def method
    ModelHelper.helper_method(self.data)
  end

  def self.method(data)
    ModelHelper.helper_method(data)
  end
end
```